# Is it possible to retrieve the TCM URI of a component from the Broker DB in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?

Tags: tridion-2011, tridion-content-delivery

Is it possible to retrieve the TCM URI of a component from the Broker DB in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1?

Comment: Please consider asking at http://tridion.stackexchange.com/ also

Answer (score 1):

If you have the `ComponentMeta` object, you can read the ID property, so the short answer is YES.

But, it is unlikely that you have `ComponentMeta` if you don't have the ID in the first place, as all the queries return a list of IDs for the Components.

Perhaps you can explain what you are actually trying to do. What is your starting point before trying to get the ID.